# Exception Reporting Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on an exception report that looks at current data that is incorrect in hope that I can find out who made the incorrect change.

As an example, here are the two datasets:

Site:

| site_no | sitetype_id |
| --- | --- |
| 601234 | R |

Site_Archive:

| row | site_no | sitetype_id | change_date | change_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 601234 | R | 2021-03-31 | 34700 |
| 2 | 601234 | R | 2021-03-30 | 34700 |
| 3 | 601234 | C | 2021-03-29 | 34700 |
| 4 | 601234 | R | 2021-03-29 | 34700 |
| 5 | 601234 | R | 2021-03-29 | 34700 |

Based on the above, I'm looking to select the record on the archive table (row 2) where the `Site_Archive.sitetype_id` is the same as the `Site.sitetype_id` but the record has to be the first one after the change in value of `Site_Archive.sitetype_id` (row 3).

I cannot for the life of me grasp the logic of how to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `the first one after the change in value of Site_Archive.sitetype_id` is that sorted by `change_date`, by `row` or  what?

Comment: change_date, I only added row so I could point to the example. I should have mentioned its not part of the dataset

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the edit, I didn't get a chance to read the OP's additional comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a stab and think I have a solution, at least with the sample data above. Using the `lag` function and ordering by what I *think* is the right combination, I can identify the sitetype_id that has changed and select the corresponding row. I'm not clear on the part played by the `row` and `change_date`, hopefully this at least gives you something to tweak.

```sql
    with a as (
        select *, Lag(sitetype_id,1) over(partition by site_no order by change_date) Xtype
        from Site_Archive
    )
    select a.row, a.site_no, a.sitetype_id, a.change_date 
    from Site s
    join a on a.site_no=s.site_no 
    where a.xtype != s.sitetype_id
```